# How to filter the table with Vue/Element-UI

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I am using Vue in combination with Element UI and I would like to show only elements in my table, which have the status 0.

I get my data by using Express, Axios, which looks like that:

```
axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tools')
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.tools = response.data;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.tools));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
}
```

So everything works fine. I get all of my stuff listed but I wanted to have tabs, with different groups of items.
Because of that I can't filter it directly where I make the database access.

So I tought why not filter it directly in the tables.

So currently the header of my table looks like this:

```
<el-table
:data="tools.filter(data => !search || data.tool_name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) || data.status == 0)"
border
fit
highlight-current-row>
```

And there you can see that I am already using a filter for my search bar.
I got it from the [example in the Doc](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table).
But I really have no idea how I can filter that I only get those elements, which "status" is == 0.

So I addet " || data.status == 0".

My columns looks like that:

```
<el-table-column align="center" label="Number" width="95">
    <template slot-scope="scope">
        {{ scope.row.tool_id }}
     </template>
 </el-table-column>
```

I hope someone have an idea!

---

Here the whole Table for better understanding:

```
    <el-tab-pane label="Verfügbare Werkzeuge">
        <el-input
          placeholder="Werkzeug suchen..."
          v-model="search"
          class="search-form">
          <i slot="prefix" class="el-input__icon el-icon-search"></i>
        </el-input>
        <el-table
        :data="tools.filter(data => !search || data.tool_name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) || data.status == 0)"
        border
        fit
        highlight-current-row>
        <el-table-column align="center" label="Werkzeugnummer" width="95">
          <template slot-scope="scope">
            {{ scope.row.tool_id }}
          </template>
        </el-table-column>
        <el-table-column label="Bezeichnung" width="120">
          <template slot-scope="scope">
            {{ scope.row.tool_name }}
          </template>
        </el-table-column>
        <el-table-column class-name="status-col" label="Status" width="110" align="center">
          <template slot-scope="scope">
            <el-tag :type="scope.row.status | statusFilter">{{ scope.row.status | nameFilter }}</el-tag>
          </template>
        </el-table-column>
        <el-table-column label="letzter Verantwortlicher" width="120">
          <template slot-scope="scope">
            {{ scope.row.used_by }}
          </template>
        </el-table-column>
        <el-table-column align="center" prop="actual_return_time" label="letzte Rückgabe" width="150">
          <template slot-scope="scope">
            <i class="el-icon-time"/>
            <span>{{ scope.row.actual_return_time }}</span>
          </template>
        </el-table-column>
      </el-table>
    </el-tab-pane>
```

Comment: please show the whole code, can't see anything here

Comment: I did. @Developerium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a problem in your filter logic. Maybe you want use your `data.status == 0` logic clause with && binary operator

Edit: pay attention on using parentheses in your logic. Besides that, you could use === to test equality including the type

Comment: I know its a little bit late, but your idea was right!

Comment: Nice! Glad to help you bro